# How to change property name in a JArray?

Tags: c#

How to change property name in a JArray? I need to change "First Name" to "fname", "Last Name" to "lname", and "Contact No" to "contact_no"?

```
  "data": [ {"First Name": "John", "Last Name": "Ben", "Contact No" : "1812"} ]
```

any body can help?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a JArray and not just `List<Dictionary<string, object>>`? In the latter case it would be as simple as just inserting a new dictionary entry named `fname` with the value of the `First Name` key and removing the `First Name` key.

Comment: the vendor use JArray and we need to change it to real field name.

Comment: If you're mapping the object from a POCO, you can use [JsonProperty("fname")].

Comment: @MattMartin could you please more detail?

Comment: If you are serializing/deserializing from a C# object, you can use serialization attributes to map your names: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm

Answer (score 0):

Just want to share, if someone also needs this.

```
            for (int _i = 0; _i < _ja_data.Count; _i++)
            {
                JObject _jo_data = (JObject)_ja_data[_i];

                foreach (JProperty jp in _jo_data.Properties().ToList())
                {
                    switch (jp.Name)
                    {
                        case "First Name":
                            {
                                jp.Replace(new JProperty("cust_fname", jp.Value));
                            }
                            break;

                        case "Last Name":
                            {
                                jp.Replace(new JProperty("cust_lname", jp.Value));
                            }
                            break;
                        case "Contact No":
                            {
                                jp.Replace(new JProperty("phone_number", jp.Value));
                            }
                            break;

                         default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var json = "{\"data\": [ {\"First Name\": \"John\", \"Last Name\": \"Ben\", \"Contact No\" : \"1812\"} ]}";

var jsonArray = (JArray)JObject.Parse(json)["data"].Dump();

var newjsonArr =new JObject(new JProperty( "data", new JArray( jsonArray.Select(a => new JObject(
                                  new JProperty("fname", a["First Name"]),
                            new JProperty("lname", a["Last Name"]),  
                              new JProperty("contact_no", a["Contact No"])
                                  )))));
```